# Setting up a service at start-up as non-root user

Tags: unix, fedora

I would like to have a service start at boot, as a non-root user on Fedora 15.

I have placed the script into /etc/init.d/, used chkconfig --add and chkconfig --level to get it all set up and it is working correctly.

What do I need to do to have it launched as non-root?

Thank you!
Kate

Comment: You could ask it to http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your current invocation of the service is:

```
 /path/to/service -o -K /var/adm/log/service.log
```

then use 'su' or 'sudo' to change to a non-root user:

```
sudo -u non-root --  /path/to/service -o -K /var/adm/log/service.log
su      non-root -c "/path/to/service -o -K /var/adm/log/service.log"
```

The double-dash is important to separate the 'options to `sudo`' from the 'options to your service'.